# Jquery counter - counting between two variable values increasing at regular intervals

Tags: php, jquery, counter

I have a strange client request that doesn't seem to fit any off-the-shelf jQuery plugins and I'm struggling to work out how best to implement.

Basically it's for a counter representing the co2 emissions projected to have been saved.
The idea is that the counter will run based on the previous months' figures.

So at the start of each month a web admin will set the start / end values.

Then over the month the page needs to load at a start point (calculated in PHP based on the date versus start point), then increment from there every 5 seconds.

So in an example:

```
startValue = 200000;
endValue = 225000;
updateInterval = 5; /* seconds */
```

We'd have 25,000 units to count up during that time.
This 25,000 should be divided by the number of 5 second increments in a month and the counter needs to increase every 5 seconds.

I think I finally understand the theory (my client sent it in the most convoluted explanation!) but I'm struggling to work out how to tackle it.

I think it's simple... but would appreciate some pointers to get me on the way!

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: Do you want the counter to do something every 5 seconds until the it hits the max? Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Sorry - I probably wasn't too clear. I've hunted around for a similar function and found this: http://www.jugit.co.uk/ - see the counter on that site's homepage. The idea here is similar, an admin will set a start and end value for the month, and over the course of the month the counter needs to progress from A to B counting up. The PHP side of things will set the starting value based on the current date and time at page load - the jQuery then needs to increment the number upwards at 5 second intervals (12 updates per min)

Comment: Then something like Ricardo's answer below should do just fine :)

Comment: Thanks Jeremy - appreciate your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe something to start:

**html:**

```
<div id="start">20</div>
<div id="end"></div>
<div id="interval">5</div>
```

**js:**

```
var start    = 21;
var end      = 25;
var interval = 5000;    

var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function(){
   if(start <= end){
      $("#start").text(start++);
   }else{
      stop();   
   }
},interval);

function stop(){
   clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);    
}​
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vax5W/16/)

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can use the javascript setInterval methid

```
setInterval(callYouFunction(), time interval in miliseconds)
```

Then increment your variables

Hope this helps